# Is there any way to transfer tokens with timestamp in smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, tokens

I have to transfer tokens from one account to another and I would like to associate a timestamp with that tokens so that i can identify which token was transferred on which time.

How do we write this code in a smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just enrich your structure in order to store the timestamp.

Consider a simple mapping like this:

```
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

to do something like you said would be enough to have a structure like this:

```
    struct Balance {
        uint amount;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    mapping (address => Balance) public balanceOf;
```

and structure your code accordingly in order to save the timestamp together with the amount.

Comment: hi, actually i am new on solidity so can you please make some changes on my code [here] (https://github.com/rkgitvinay/test-contract) .

Comment: You already got the hint, try to modify your code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the timestamp within the contract, you could just use the transaction block's timestamp. So whenever a token is transferred you can check in which block it was and check its timestamp.

But if you need to store the info in the contract itself then @mirg's answer will do.